# Defining Model relations between Identity and User using omniauth and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a rails 4 start up, with devise and omniauth, along with twitter bootstrap and can can.

But my understanding of models isn't so good, hence I am running into a problem with user and identity model.

Identity Model

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "uid"
```

...

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include User::AuthDefinitions
  include User::Roles

  has_many :identities

  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name
```

The small github repository is here -: https://github.com/pratik60/tur.

I am sure the problem is because of my lack of understanding of model relations, but I get this error, when I try to sign up -: NameError: uninitialized constant User::Identity basically uninitialized constant User::Identity

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can get the identities by `User.first.identities` not `User::Identity`..thanks

Comment: The error is here -: identities.empty? Why does that give an error?

Comment: yes as the user does not have any identities so first create some identities User.first.identities.create!(IDENTITY PARAMETER)

Comment: it just says undefined method identites for Nil:Nil class

Comment: you do not have any user in database create at least an user then try that

Comment: I added admin, so it does work now...

Comment: yes as admin is one type of user so user has many identities so it will work ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

The foreign_key parameter should be in the User Model.

Try this in your User model :

```
has_many :identities, class_name: "Identity", foreign_key: "uid"
```

And this in your Identity model :

```
belongs_to :user
```